# LXML: How to find all custom tags like xi:something in an xml

Tags: python, lxml

My XML:

```
<sample>
    <sample1>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
    </sample1>
    <sample2>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
    </sample2>
</sample>
```

I have to find all the `<xi:something>` using python
I have tried `lxml and xml` library of the python 3.6 but was not find the tags marked with `xi:something`.

Comment: Use namespaces: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

Answer (score 1):

You should first fix your XML and use a proper [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) for the `xi` prefix. Let the file `so.xml` contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sample xmlns:xi="urn:xi">
    <sample1>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
    </sample1>
    <sample2>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
        <xi:something href="sample.html" tags="something"/>
    </sample2>
</sample>
```

Then you can use [XPath and namespaces](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes):

```
from lxml import etree

x = etree.parse(open("so.xml"))

something = x.xpath("//xi:something", namespaces={"xi": "urn:xi"})
for s in something:
    print(s.tag)
    print(s.get("href"))
    print(s.get("tags"))
```

The output will be:

```
{urn:xi}something
sample.html
something
{urn:xi}something
sample.html
something
...
```